# Haskell: Evaluating lambda expressions manually - determine general types

Tags: haskell, lambda, evaluation, lambda-calculus

First of all, sorry if I'm not not posting this on the correct site since I'm not sure if it's more of a mathematical question than a programming one, but since I'm using this with Haskell and comparing the results with a Haskell interpreter, I just thought I'd ask it here.

So I'm basically trying to evaluate lambda expressions in Haskell and I'm doing it manually (in preparation for an exam, since I'll be forced to do it on paper). I'm given some expressions and I have to write down their general types after they're evaluated. To do so, I'm using an interpreter to get a somewhat correct answer.

In particular, I'm going to evaluate the following expressions:

```
t2 = ( \x y z  -> y.x.y );
tx2 = (\x y z -> y.z.z);
tp2 = (\x -> \y -> (x.y.x));
td2 = (\x y z f -> y(z(z(f))));
tm2 = (\z -> \y -> \x -> z.y.x);
```

Since I don't 100% understand how to do this, I've devised a method. First, I create a template that somewhat resembles what the evaluated expression will look like. I.E. if part of the left-size ('lambda'd') variable is featured on the right side (as it's pretty much functional composition in every case), it's a function. If not, it's just a variable. Afterwards, I'm trying to fit the general types of the functions as best as I can and I'm getting some semi-right results, but I'm sure I'm still making some mistakes. Here's my whole evaluation process:

```
t2 = ( \x y z -> y.x.y );

(_ -> _) -> (_ -> _) -> c -> _ -> _

y(x(y))
assume: 
y :: a -> b
x :: b -> a

result: (b -> a) -> (a -> b) -> c -> a -> b
interpreter: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> c -> b -> a
```

z isn't featured on the right side, so it's not a function in this case. I'm assigning it c. Now I'm looking at the composition on the right side. I'm going right to left and I assign a -> b to y since I have no idea about it's input or output. Since x uses the result of y as an input, and y uses x' output as an input again, x is b -> a. Which I can just insert into my template.
As you can see, it's not exactly the same result as I get via the interpreter, but it's only a and b being switched around, so it doesn't seem that wrong.

```
tx2 = (\x y z -> y.z.z);

a -> (_ -> _) -> (_ -> _) -> _ -> _

y(z(z))
assume: 
z :: b -> b
y :: b -> c

result: a -> (b -> c) -> (b -> b) -> b -> c
interpreter: a -> (b -> c) -> (b -> b) -> b -> c
```

Same as above. Since z uses itself in functional composition, I assume it has the same input and output. y uses z's output as input and has some unknown output, hence c. This appears to be in line with my interpreter.

```
tp2 = (\x -> \y -> (x.y.x));

(_ -> _) -> (_ -> _) -> _ -> _

x(y(x))
assume: 
x :: a -> b
y :: b -> a

result: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> a -> b
interpreter: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> a -> b
```

Pretty much the same as the first example, only I don't have an unused lambda variable.

```
td2 = (\x y z f -> y(z(z(f))));

a -> (_ -> _) -> (_ -> _) -> (_ -> _) -> _ -> _

y(z(z(f)))
assume:
f :: _ -> b
z :: b -> b
y :: b -> c

assume: a -> (b -> c) -> (b -> b) -> (_ -> b) -> b -> c
result: a -> (b -> c) -> (b -> b) -> (b -> b) -> b -> c
interpreter: a -> (b -> c) -> (b -> b) -> b -> c
```

Everything but x is a function in this case. f's Input isn't initially known to me and I'm just leaving it empty at the time. z uses f's output and it's own output in composition, so I just assign it b -> b. y uses z's output, and has an unknown output itself, so it gets b -> c. 
Now I insert it into my template, but I'm still missing an input for f. Since there's a b right after f, I just assume it uses b as an input, too.
**Now there's the first real question:** where did f disappear to in the answer given by the interpreter? I can only assume since it uses the same input/output as z and it's basically in composition with it, it just got simplified into a single b->b, but I'm not sure about this.

```
tm2 = (\z -> \y -> \x -> z.y.x);
tm2 = (\z y x -> z.y.x);

(_ -> _) -> (_ -> _) -> (_ -> _) -> _ -> _

z(y(x))
assume:
x = a -> b
y = b -> _
z = _ -> _

assume: (_ -> _) -> (b -> _) -> (a -> b) -> _ -> _
result?: (a -> c) -> (b -> a) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
interpreter: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> (d -> c) -> d -> b
```

**Here's where it all falls apart:** z, y, and x are functions. So I'm just assigning a -> b to x, which means that y's input is b. The output is unknown to me at this time. Same goes for z, since I have no idea about y's output.
So after I enter them in my template, the only thing that's really left for me is just to fill in the blanks for unknown values. Since x would require a as input, it means that there's an a right after it. Which would mean that it's z's input, too. Since it's z's input, I can assume it's y's output. The only thing left to fill in is z's output, and I just assign it a c since I don't really know what it could be.

As you can see, this isn't what the interpreter gives me, at all. While the left hand side might be still somewhat similar, I don't understand what happens on the right hand side, at all. Why is it d -> b? Shouldn't it be whatever's the result of (z(y(x))), which should have z's input/output?

Thanks in advance for any help you might offer me.

Answer (score 2):

There are three basic properties you can exploit:

1. Due to currying, `\x y -> z` is equivalent to `\x -> \y -> z`.
2. For any `x(y)`, you know that `x` must be a function and its first argument matches the type of the expression `y`.
3. You know the type of `.`, which is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. Furthermore, `.` is right-associative (i.e. `a.b.c` is the same as `a.(b.c)`).

With this in mind, consider your first example:

```
t2 = ( \x y z  -> y.x.y );
```

Clearly, it's a function of three arguments, so its type will be something akin to

```
t2 :: ty0 -> ty1 -> ty2 -> ty3
```

I use `ty0` through `ty3` here to denote the types to infer. `ty0` is the type of the `x` argument, `ty1` is for `y`, `ty2` for `z` and `ty3` is the type of the result value (i.e. the type of the expression `y.x.y`).

I'd start with determining the type `ty3` (which is defined by the expression `y.x.y`) because while doing so you'll also find the types of the *used* arguments. Unused arguments can have any type:

1. `y.x.y` is equivalent to `y.(x.y)` (due to right-associativity of `.`, see item #3 above). So you can start by considering the subexpression `x.y`.
2. This means that `x :: (b -> c)` and `y :: (a -> b)` and hence `x.y :: a -> c` (due to the type of `.`, again see #3 above).
3. So we know that `y :: (a -> b)` and `x.y :: a -> c`. With this in mind, the only way `y.(x.y)` can type check (i.e. match the type of `.`) is when `c ~ a`, i.e. `c` and `a` are the same type.

Hence, `x :: b -> a` (our `ty0`!) and `y :: a -> b` `(`ty1`) and`y.(x.y) :: a -> b`(what we called`ty3` above). You can plug this into our primitive 'three-argument function type' above.

```
t2 :: ty0 -> ty1 -> ty2 -> ty3
=>
t2 :: (b -> a) -> (a -> b) -> ty2 -> (a -> b)
```

...and since `->` is right-associative, you can omit the last parens (and instead of `ty2` you could have used `c`, of course).

Let's try the same strategy on your last example:

```
tm2 = (\z -> \y -> \x -> z.y.x);
```

1. This is equivalent to `\z y x -> z.y.x` (due to currying, see #1 in the list at the top).
2. This means it's another three-argument function of the form `tm2 :: ty0 -> ty1 -> ty2 -> ty3`. Again, we start by inferring the type `ty3` by considering the definition of the function.
3. The type `ty3` is the type of the expression `z.y.x`, which is equivalent to `z.(y.x)` (due to right-associativity of `.`).
4. All three variables must be functions to satisfy the type of `.` (see #3 in the list at the top).
5. So `x :: a -> b`, `y :: b -> c`, `y.x :: a -> c`.
6. From this, it follows that `z :: c -> d` and hence `z.y.x :: a -> d`.

Since `z` is the first argument to `tm2`, `y` is the second and `x` is the third argument, you can tell that

```
tm2 :: (c -> d) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> d)
```

Comment: Similarly, for `tx2 = (\x y z -> y.z.z);` you can see that 1. `x` is unused, 2. `y` can be composed with `z` and 3. `z` can be composed with itself, so you get `tx2 :: a -> (b -> c) -> (b -> b) -> b -> c`.

Comment: How do you (or should we) parse `y.x.y`? If it's `y (x y)`, then your type doesn't seem right, if it's `y x y`, then it's an occurs check.

Comment: I read it as function composition, I.e. `x.y` meaning `\a -> x (y a)`.

Comment: Oh. I guess the lack of spaces threw me off.

Comment: Since `.` is *actually* associative, the "right-associative" aspect of its syntax is irrelevant here.